# kendoui websharper and failed to access method from another model

Tags: f#, websharper

Learning something new is always following something what already exists. So I reconfigure this example (http://www.websharper.com/samples/KendoChart) which works fine. (only graph on line 12.  I saved series into some variable and it looks like this. 
So line 12 should be.

```
let Chart chartType stack = 
        let  data =  [|

                        chart.SeriesConfiguration (
                            Name = "World",
                            Data = [|15.7 ; 16.7 ; 20. ; 23.5; 26.6|]
                        )

                        chart.SeriesConfiguration (
                            Name = "United States",
                            Data = [|67.96 ; 68.93 ; 75. ; 74. ; 78.|]
                        )
                    |]
```

Where data is on line 36 Series = data... and that works fine.
 But what if I want my data to be ...

```
 let Chart chartType stack = 
        let techs = StoneMiner.Charts.technologies()
        let  data = seq { for i in techs do 
                        yield  chart.SeriesConfiguration (
                                 Name = fst i ,
                            Data =[|snd i|]//; 16.7 ; 20. ; 23.5; 26.6|]
                        ) }
                   |> Seq.toArray
```

where let techs = StoneMiner.Charts.technologies() is technologies is in another Namespace and module...

I get some strange error... 
Error   1   Failed to translate a method call: technologies(..) [StoneMiner.Charts]. Because it is in another modul.

Answer (score 4):

It seems your function `StomeMiner.Charts.technologies` doesn't have a `[<JavaScript>]` annotation. This prevents it from being translated into JavaScript and thus used on client-side.

As a rule of thumb, anything you use from the client-side needs to be annotated with one of the attributes from `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core.Attributes` (which are accessible directly when you open `IntelliFactory.WebSharper`). Depending on the situation, it can be `[<JavaScript>]` (for translation to JS), `[<Inline "...">]` (to inline some JS code), `[<Remote>]` (for Ajax RPC calls to the server) or less common ones like `[<Stub>]` or `[<Direct>]`.

Comment: Oh tnx for answer. I thought that something like this would be solution but didn't know what exactly. But what If I have inside that technologies() regex expressions like I do actually and get the same error error.  Failed to translate a method call: Replace(..) [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex. Maybe is also trivial solution but dunno :-\

Comment: Or some other method from another module which I made.

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript regexes, you will need to use the `RegExp` type from `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.EcmaScript`.